# html/css/js with wordpress backend

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Can I create custom html/css/js pages and use them with wordpress backend like user registration/login, woo commerce, mail senders, and other stuff wordpress has to offer? Googled a lot, but it gets more and more unclear. Would appreciate if someone who can explain this concept. Need to do a simple 3-5 items e-commerce website, but more like a landing page for each product.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Regard wordpress folder as another PHP website, nothing detars you putting some custom static/flat-files like static HTML or PHP pages.

Lets try a simple one, putting `bootstrap-home.php` inside it, put the bootstrap example page.

Also, make another same file, `bootstrap-home.html` and copy same contents, you will see both pages rendering.

Now, if you want to call database, or interact with wordpress functionalities like mails, and other things - which you need to find. Then you will need to write your own stuffs for validation, spam and other things.

Better not go in that route, if being attacked by spams.
But simple answer is, Wordpress is a PHP folder, flat-php or flat-html files will be served.